# How to find the problem of kinect when rostopic echo get nothing

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I plugin the kinect.

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

rosrun rviz rviz
```

setup the msg type [PointCloud2]

and topic [/camera/depth/points]

and the reference frame [/camera_depth_frame]

But the status indicates no messages received. How can I make sure it's the problem from kinect or from openni?

---

modified)

To clarify my problem:

I do rostopic echo [topic] and get nothing. It may not be the problem of Rviz and the viewing tools. I doubt this is the hardware and driver problem, and possibly the graphic card driver? This problem happened on my laptop while my desktop worked fine. Both of them are Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte. I got bumblebee on my laptop but not on the desktop.

Some messages appear in the shell where I roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch :

```
[ERROR] [1355549619.381311998]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1355549619.393316233]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1355549619.406856824]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
[ INFO] [1355549620.217247774]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1355549620.217803421]: 1. device on bus 003:05 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00365A18349102A'
[ INFO] [1355549620.219848686]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1355549620.260220331]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 3:5 with serial number 'A00365A18349102A'
[ INFO] [1355549620.280287325]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1355549620.280362638]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1355549620.284242802]: Camera calibration file /home/albert/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00365A18349102A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1355549620.284296968]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1355549620.284377146]: Camera calibration file /home/albert/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00365A18349102A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1355549620.284421645]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

I think that these warnings and errors shouldn't result in such problem. Besides, the info may tell us that the device driver is fine.

How to solve this? Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50346/how-to-find-the-problem-of-kinect-when-rostopic-echo-get-nothing/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-12-13**:
Does `rostopic echo /camera/depth/points` print anything?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-12-13**:
I have met the same problem. In my case, it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An easier way to see if the data from the Kinect is being received by the drivers and computer than by setting up rviz is with the command `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color`, which should display an RGB image from the Kinect camera if the driver is functioning properly. Remember to have roscore and the driver running in the background. More information is on the openni_launch page.

---

Originally posted by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) with karma: 93 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-12-13**:
I have met the same problem. In my case, it shows the window but without any image.

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-12-14**:
It looks like another way to take and display the sensor data from the topic, but the situation is that rostopic echo get nothing.

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2012-12-15**:
assuming that you are using fuerte and have downloaded openni_launch and openni_camera, I would suggest trying alternate USB ports for the kinect and potentially even reinstalling those drivers. Seems that you are doing the right things, so just fiddle around a bit more.